# Creating a symlink from one folder to another with different names?

Tags: webserver, symbolic-link

I have two folders, one of which is my webserver root. I want to link it to my project folder so that I can keep things up-to-date with Git.

If I try to do this:

```
ln -s /home/user/project  /var/www/html
```

The system creates a folder called *project* within the html folder, and links that. Is there any way to link it so that the directory 'html' points to the contents of *project*? Do they have to be the same name?

**Note**: I also need to link several hidden files. Can I do this using `ln`?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

From `man ln`:

> By default, each destination (name of new link) should not already exist.

As you already have a directory named `html`, the link will be created inside `/var/www/html` having the name of the target i.e. `project`.

If you want to have a symlink `/var/www/html` pointing to `/home/user/project` then you should not have the directory `html` present beforehand. So, you should only have `/var/www` and then running the following will create the desired symlink (don't do this unless you are sure):

```
ln -s /home/user/project /var/www/html
```

**Note**: if you use a trailing slash (like in `ln -s /home/user/project /var/www/html/`) you will get an error: `ln: target '/var/www/html' is not a directory: No such file or directory`.

Here is an example:

```bash
$ pwd
/home/user/test/askubuntu

$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Mar 25 00:16 foo

$ ln -s /home/user/test/bar /home/user/test/askubuntu/foo

$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Mar 25 00:17 foo

$ cd foo/
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 25 Mar 25 00:17 bar -> /home/user/test/bar

$ cd ..
$ rm -r foo/

$ ls -l
total 0

$ ln -s /home/user/test/bar /home/user/test/askubuntu/foo

$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 25 Mar 25 00:18 foo -> /home/user/test/bar
```

And yes, you can create symlinks of hidden files.

Comment: I tried this but the resulting symlink was a file and not a directory

Comment: @Alex a softlink appears like a file but the result is that it behaves like the folder it was pointing at.

Comment: Also note that the source directory must not be relative path must be absolute so `ln -s ./ /var/www/html` will not work

Comment: `ln -s $PWD/path/to/real/dir ./relative/path/to/symlink` the second arg can be relative (at least on darwin/BSD)

Comment: @DiegoAndrésDíazEspinoza THAT IS IMPORTANT, was wondering why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 8):

Make sure html directory is not created under `/var/www/`.

The command then is: `ln -s -T /home/user/project /var/www/html`