# Sync Desktops between two computers via Dropbox?

Tags: gnome, dropbox, symbolic-link

I've been using Dropbox and symlinks to keep two Ubuntu computers in sync, for years.

The setup is a bit fiddly, because some links go TO the Dropbox folder, and some come FROM it, depending on how things are set up, but I haven't had any problems.

Now, I want to simplify things, but I'm a bit concerned about existing directories. Specifically, Desktop, Downloads, and Pictures.

My thinking is that it should be ok to do, on both computers, this:

```
me@computer:~$ ln -sfn /home/me/Dropbox/Desktop /home/me/Desktop
```

But maybe Gnome treats Desktop as some sort of special directory. I tried it with the Downloads directory, and the system won't allow me overwrite it, even with sudo.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/600714/creating-a-symlink-from-one-folder-to-another-with-different-

Comment: I'd have to delete /home/user/Desktop for the first option to work and then create it with the ln command. I don't know what would happen if I tried that. Mount bind, which I hadn't heard of, sounds much better. Thank you.

Comment: I want to test that bind on a vm to see how it plays with Desktop and will let you know

Comment: I mounted the Downloads directory and it works very well. I've only noticed two details: 1) the Nautilus windows says 250 GB Volume, instead of Home - Me - Downloads. If I CTRL-L to see the path, it reports it correctly: /home/me/Downloads. 2) When I delete a file, it says "<filename> can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?" Other than that, I haven't found any problems. Next up, set it up to survive a reboot!

Comment: Ah, it also mounted the entire hard drive to the Desktop! 0_o

Comment: Can I see the out of this command `df -h` and note it should be `~/Dropbox  ~/Desktop    none   rw,bind    0      0`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `mount` command's `bind` option to sync the two computers as this would prevent the removal of the `Desktop` folder so the `link` command would not re-create the `Dropbox` folder in that location. The terminal command to use to achieve this is:

```
sudo mount --bind ~/Dropbox  ~/Desktop
```

or

```
sudo mount -o bind ~/Dropbox  ~/Desktop
```

To make this permanent add the following line to the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/home/$USER/Dropbox         /home/$USER/Desktop    none     rw,bind,nowaitboot     0     0
```

This `nowaitboot` ensures that if the dropbox folder isn't there your system will still boot.